# Could I use controllers from an application that has been added as a JAR dependency?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, dependencies

I am working on Springboot application(app_A) that holds a Maven dependency to another SpringBoot application (app_B).
In my app_A I need to use controllers present in App_B. Is  it possible to do that? And if yes, how could that be implemented?
Thanks

Comment: It depends if B is wrapped up as a Spring Boot application as well (i.e. a runnable jar, then no). If it is a regular jar that happens to use Spring Boot (i.e. a non-runnable jar) then yes. Judging by your question I would say option 1 is in play here so no. How to change read the [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-an-additional-executable-jar).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @M.Deinum ! I have already used https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-an-additional-executable-jar to generate a JAR that could be used as a dependency.  Classes from appB could be reached from appA( for example using import). So my concern here is about using or calling appB's controllers . For example using a Model attribute that has been set in appB's controllers in appA's thymeleaf code. Note that appB has been created a SpringBoot application and not a module.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common scenario where programmers need to separate some codes from the existing application stack.

You can do it either in `app A depends on module B` or `app A consumes app B's rest APIs`, but you cannot let `app A depends on app B`. A Springboot application (A) can never depend on another Springboot application (B), in other words, application (B) cannot appear in A's dependencies.

## New Module

Build a new module called, artifactId `module-b`. Note that we are building a **module** instead of a Springboot application. You cannot use the Spring initializer for this.

## Let App A Depend on Module B

In A's maven dependencies, add module B.

## Write controllers in Module B

For example, your existing App A controllers are placed in A like, `com.example.foo.BarController`. In module B, you code new controllers like `com.example.foo.AnotherController`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @justthink ! What if  I want  to change my AppB Spring boot application into a Module ? what should I exactly take into consideration ?

Comment: The approach outlined in this comment is also briefly described here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-dependency
That post also contains a solution where you *can* depend on app B inside app A, although I would not recommend to do it, as it's a much cleaner architecture to separate out the business logic (and maybe controllers) that you actually need into another maven project